# Sometimes I have Timeout exception when I send APN to apple server

Tags: c#, apple-push-notifications, http2

my code :

```
var uri = new Uri($"{domain}/3/device/{deviceToken}");

var client = new Http2Client(uri); // using HttpTwo

var headers = new NameValueCollection
{
    {"apns-id", Guid.NewGuid().ToString()},
    {"apns-expiration", "0"},
    {"apns-priority", "10"},
    {"apns-topic", topic},
    {"authorization", $"bearer {jwtToken}"}
};

var body = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload));

var response = await client.Send(uri,HttpMethod.Post, headers, body);
```

this code give proper response most of the time but once in a while I get the operation has timed out Exception.

> ---> System.TimeoutException: The operation has timed out.
>   at HttpTwo.Http2Client.d__19.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>   at HttpTwo.Http2Client.d__17.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>   at HttpTwo.Http2Client.d__15.MoveNext()

Comment: We have this also. Did you found any solution?

Comment: I hav the same problem, solutions?

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue on one of my servers, running Windows Server 2016 datacenter edition. Tried on two PCs and getting very different results on there and the server. The only difference from this snippet is that I'm using HttpTwo's HttpClient API instead of the Http2Client - but also tried going with the Http2Client directly and got the same results. Tried targeting .Net 4.5.2 and 4.7 

So on the server, about 50% of the pushes are running to timeout. On one of my PCs (both Windows 10), about 10% of the pushes. On the other PC, all requests timing out. Anyone any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can set  Http2Client.ConnectionSettings.ConnectionTimeout for your connection so it will be more predictable )))
And you should implement reconnect logic for apns connection.
Something like this:

```
int retry = 0;
 while (retry < 1)
 {
     try
    {
        var response = await client.Send(uri,HttpMethod.Post, headers, body);
        break;
    }
    catch (TimeoutException)
    {
        retry++;
    }
}
```

From documentation:

Keep your connections with APNs open across multiple notifications; do not repeatedly open and close connections. APNs treats rapid connection and disconnection as a denial-of-service attack. You should leave a connection open unless you know it will be idle for an extended period of time—for example, if you only send notifications to your users once a day, it is acceptable practice to use a new connection each day.